# k-Nearest Neighbor: Error Rate Increases as K Increases

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, nearest-neighbor

[image]I am doing a KNN analysis on the FIFA 2019 dataset on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19)
This dataset has 18159 rows after eliminating N/A values.

I am trying to predict if a player is an 'attacker' based on various characteristics such as stamina, shotpower, finishing, overall (their rating), etc.

We consider a player an attacker if their positions are either LS, ST, RS, RF, LF, or CF.

I'm confused why the error rate is increasing as the number of K increases (I graphed for 10 nearest neighbors). I thought it was usually the other way around, that when you consider more neighbors the error rate tends to go down?

Does anyone think there is something wrong with this approach, or could explain why they think the error rate is increasing?

New to machine learning, any insight is appreciated

```
sampledata<-data
sampledata$indicator = "No"

for(i in 1:NROW(sampledata)){
  if (sampledata$Position[i] == "ST" | sampledata$Position[i] == "LS" | sampledata$Position[i] == "RS"| sampledata$Position[i] == "RF" | sampledata$Position[i] == "LF" | sampledata$Position[i] == "CF"){
    sampledata$indicator[i] = "Yes"
  }
}

print(head(sampledata))

sampledata = sampledata[,c("Overall","Finishing","Positioning","ShotPower","Balance","Stamina","Strength","indicator")]

sampledata <- na.omit(sampledata)   #eliminate any na values
any(is.na(sampledata))

sampledata$Overall <- as.numeric(sampledata$Overall)
sampledata$Finishing <- as.numeric(sampledata$Finishing)
sampledata$Positioning <- as.numeric(sampledata$Positioning)
sampledata$ShotPower <- as.numeric(sampledata$ShotPower)
sampledata$Balance <- as.numeric(sampledata$Balance)
sampledata$Stamina <- as.numeric(sampledata$Stamina)
sampledata$Strength <- as.numeric(sampledata$Strength)
sampledata$indicator <- as.numeric(as.factor((sampledata$indicator)))

library(caTools)
sample = sample.split(sampledata, SplitRatio = .80)   #take random sample of 80% of rows to make training data
test_knn <- sampledata[-sample,]
test_attacker <- sampledata$indicator[-sample]
train_knn <- sampledata[sample,]
train_attacker <- sampledata$indicator[sample]

#Choose a K value
library(class)
predicted.attacker <- NULL
error.rate <- NULL

for (i in 1:10){
  set.seed(101)
  predicted.attacker <- knn(train_knn,test_knn,train_attacker,k=i)
  error.rate[i] <- mean(test_attacker != predicted.attacker)
}

print(error.rate)

#visualize K elbow method
library(ggplot2)
k.values <- 1:10
error.df <- data.frame(error.rate,k.values)
print(error.df)   #shows error rate for each k value

ggplot(error.df,aes(k.values,error.rate)) + geom_point() +
  geom_line(lty='dotted',color='red')
```

Comment: How many rows does your dataframe have? Perform the same procedure for the `1:sqrt(nrow(df))`.

Comment: Hi @bbiasi there are 18159 rows. What do you mean by performing the same procedure for the 1:sqrt(nrow(df))? Where in the code would that go?

Comment: Make it up to 100, the value is high, but just so you can better visualize the errors for other values of k. `for (i in 1:100)`. If at no time does it stabilize or you do not check for reduction, something may be wrong. I leave the suggestion of the `factoextra` package, which can help you in understanding the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it continues to follow the same trend (error rate increasing). Do you know if there are ever circumstances where it's ok that the error rate is increasing? @bbiasi

Comment: Did you handle the database?

Comment: If yes, try using the `caret` package to check if you will have the same result.

Comment: Please check the SO post here for a clear explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271270/why-testing-error-rate-increases-at-high-values-of-k-in-knn-algorithm